# Highcharts age pyramid stacked bar (grouping)

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I would like to use the highcharts age pyramid for men and women. Men and women can fall into three different categories. For example a, b and c. I would like to have a stacked bar for the three groups for men and women separately per age. Hopefully you can help me with this.

I have created the following age pyramid [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/o4xbtcgk/), but as you can see, it has not yet been possible to add more than two groups.

JavaScript

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 10
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    left: '50%',
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: -18
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Age Group',
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      x: 40
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
    left: '55%',
    width: '45%',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: -160,
      text: 'Female'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }, {
    reversed: true,
    width: '45%',
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: 170,
      text: 'Male'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }],

  series: [{
    data: [1, 3],
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#3F7EBF'],
        [1, '#1F3F5F']
      ]
    },
  }, {
    data: [2, 5],
        color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#980061'],
        [1, '#4C0030']
      ]
    },
    yAxis: 1
  }]
});
```

This is what i want to achieve in the end:

[image: This is what i want to achieve in the end]

Comment: Can you add a drawing or pic of what you want?  Do you want another age group? https://jsfiddle.net/7pvxcjg1/

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not supported yet. You can report it on Highcharts user voice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api or contact with BlackLabel company (experts of charting Highcharts): https://blacklabel.pl

Comment: Hi Barbara, what i want is the following: https://www.mupload.nl/img/n6hvwyz7qxvw.24.16.jpeg

Comment: @WojciechChmiel are you using stackoverflow to get customers?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio no, I've suggested what the author can do to get the solution that is not supported by Highcharts library. UserVoice is a place where new ideas can be added and if there will be enough user votes the idea will be implemented. On the other hand, BlackLabel company cooperate with Highsoft (Highcharts distributor) and they are making projects that are beyond the scope of the Highcharts library (faster solution than waiting on UserVoice).

Comment: @WojciechChmiel you left the name of your company in your comment offering yourself for consulting job outside of stackoverflow. I believe you should engage with customers on other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chart type is not supported by Highcharts library out of the box.

However, something similar can be created using two charts next to each other with one axis reversed. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21', '21-25'],
    labels: {
     enabled: false
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    reversed: true,
    title: {
      text: 'males',
      align: 'high'
    }
  },
  credits: {
   enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'A',
    data: [5, 3, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    data: [2, 2, 3]
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    data: [3, 4, 4]
  }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21', '21-25'],
    labels: {
     align: 'center'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'females',
      align: 'low'
    }
  },
  credits: {
   enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'A',
    data: [2, 4, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    data: [5, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    data: [4, 1, 2]
  }]
});
```

```css
#container1 {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}

#container2 {
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cg5af2dz/

Comment: Thanks @Wojciech Chmiel, i like the solution with two separate boxes. I like both solutions but unfortunately I can only give one person the bounty, so I gave it to the first person who answered the question. But would also like to thank @ User863!

Answer (score 1):

Just a multiple `series` of data

```
series: [{
    name: 'A (m)',
    data: [6, 2],
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    name: 'B (m)',
    data: [2, 2],
    yAxis: 1
  }, 
  ... 
]
```

and [`stacking: 'normal'`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.stacking)

```
series: {
   stacking: 'normal'
}
```

solves the problem

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 170,
    marginLeft: 10
  },

  title: '',

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    },
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    left: '50%',
    categories: ['15-19', '20-21'],
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0,
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'left',
      x: -18
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'right',
      x: 20
    },
    title: {
      text: 'age group',
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      x: 40
    }
  },

  yAxis: [{
    left: '55%',
    width: '45%',
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: -210,
      text: 'males'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }, {
    reversed: true,
    width: '45%',
    offset: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      x: 210,
      text: 'females'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'left',
      x: -20
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0
  }],

  series: [{
    name: 'A (m)',
    data: [6, 2],
    color: '#000',
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    name: 'B (m)',
    data: [2, 2],
    color: '#02aff1',
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    name: 'C (m)',
    data: [2, 2],
    color: '#e0301e',
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    name: 'A (f)',
    data: [2, 2],
    color: '#000',
  }, {
    name: 'B (f)',
    data: [2, 2],
    color: '#02aff1',
  }, {
    name: 'C (f)',
    data: [6, 2],
    color: '#e0301e',
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @User863, I like both solutions but unfortunately I can only give one person the bounty, so I gave it to the first person who answered the question. But would also like to thank you!